# Hash Functions - Truncation and Division

Tags: c++

So my problem was that I was trying to use a truncation hash function as a collision index increment/decrement... I had to use it as the first main function, and use a more uniform hash function as the second hash function in its place.

My corrected code is below:

```
// ============================ HASH FUNCTIONS ============================ \\


  // Hash function 1 (Base-26)
  int Hash_1(char *key2)
  {
        int index;
        index = (int)((key2[0] - 'A' + 1) * pow(26, 3)) + ((key2[1] - 'A' + 1) * pow(26, 2)) + ((key2[2] - 'A' + 1) * 26) + ((key2[3] - 'A' + 1));
        return (index % TABLESIZE);
  }


  // Hash function 2 (Folding)
  int Hash_2(char *key2)
  {
        int index;
        index = ((key2[0] - 'A' + 1) * (key2[1] - 'A' + 1)) + ((key2[2] - 'A' + 1) * (key2[3] - 'A' + 1));
        return (index % TABLESIZE); 
  }


  // Hash function 3 (Truncation)
  int Hash_3(char *key2)
  {
        int index;
        index = ((key2[1] - 'A' + 1) * (key2[2] - 'A' + 1));
        return (index % TABLESIZE);
  }

// ========================= DOUBLE HASH FUNCTIONS ========================= \\


  // Double hash 1 (Linear Probing)
  int ProbeDec_1(char *key2)
  {
      return 1;
  }


  // Double hash 2 (Middle Squaring)
  int ProbeDec_2(char *key2)
  {
      int index;
      index = (int)pow(((key2[1] - 'A' + 1) + (key2[2] - 'A' + 1)), 2);
      return (index % TABLESIZE);
  }


  // Double hash 3 (Division)
  int ProbeDec_3(char *key2)
  {
      int index;
      int primeNum = 7;
      index = max((key2[3] / primeNum), 1) % primeNum;
      return (index % TABLESIZE);
  }
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @Creris How do I implement the division and truncation hash functions with a 4-letter key?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a perfect "hash" for 4-*letter* strings.

There are less than 32 letters in the latin alphabet, there are less than 64 letters in the latin alphabet if you distinguish between upper and lower case letters.

Why mention 32 and 64? Because they are fifth and sixth powers of two.
We can create a 32 bit integer that uniquely represents a 4-letter word (distinguishing between upper and lower letters) as follows:

- bits 0 to 5 encode the first letter of the string
- bits 6 to 11 encode the second
- bits 12 to 17 encode the third
- bits 18 to 23 encode the fourth
- bits 24 to 31 are set to 0

By encode, I mean something like:

- "A" is encoded as 000000
- "a" is encoded as 000001
- "B" is 000010
- "b" is 000011
  and so on. We know we can fit all the letters in whatever encoding you want because there are fewer letters than there are available bit arrangements.

You can even encode each letter as `key - 'A' + 1`, as you seem to prefer.

I would strongly suggest you create a function that takes a character and returns its encoded value. Generally, if you find yourself writing the same piece of code in more than 3 places, you should consider making it a function.

Equally important, since writing hash functions is mostly about bit-fiddling, you should learn how to use the shift operators `<`  and `>` instead of `pow`.

You should also learn about integer operations.
What exactly do you thing `1 / (1 - (key2[2] - 'A' + 1))` can possibly return?

None of your functions can be called "hash functions".
If you want to use something like "truncation" or "division" you should first figure out what that means.

Comment: I edited the code above... I just need help figuring out if my  truncation (ProbeDec_2) function is good or not... It goes into an endless loop when I try to implement it as a second hash function. By the way, all the letters being read in are capital, A-Z, so only 26 characters available for each slot.

Comment: @tomkelley13 `ProbeDec_2` is as bad as all the others. Perhaps the problem is in another part of your code? I recommend you try this hash function in its own test app, and see how it behaves for some sample input.

Comment: Everytime I use Truncation, the results are far far worse than any other hash function.... I've tried switching up the order, and the results are the same. I guess Truncation is just terrible for hashing 4-letter keys.

Comment: @tomkelley13 Well, you are looking at only half the data. So, you have `26*26` possible return values (mod your `TABLESIZE` which, btw, should not be part of the hash, the hash is a property of the data, independent of its "usage") but `26*26*26*26` possible strings...